# Passing yubikey pin to windows

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, paramiko, yubikey

I am using WSL to run python/paramiko scripts. On the windows side, I use pageant for key management with a yubikey. From the same WSL window, when I run standard SSH, I'm only prompted once for the yubikey pin. With paramiko, I get prompted on every run. Is there any way to cache the pin for paramiko too or pass it in the python code?

I expected paramiko to behave the same as standard ssh